# How to add authentication to controller tests Spring?

Tags: spring, junit, spring-security, mockito

I added a basic auth to my Spring app in application.properties like this:

```html
  #Security
  security:
    user:
      name: admin
      password: admin
```

I also added spring-boot-starter-security to make it work. Now I'm curious how I need to refactor controller tests as after I implemented basic auth all of those tests returned 401 status. I am using junit5 and mockito. This is the ControllerTests class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = BooksApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class BookControllerTests {
@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
ObjectMapper mapper;
@MockBean
BookController bookController;

@Autowired
private BookConverter converter;

@Test
public void createBook_success() throws Exception {
    Book book = Book.builder().name("Great book").author("Ivan")
            .pagesNumber(340).publisher("New Publisher").build();
    BookDto dto = converter.toDto(book);

    given(bookController.createBook(dto)).willReturn(dto);

    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/books/create")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(asJsonString(book)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}

@Test
public void getAllBooks_success() throws Exception {

    Book book1 = Book.builder().name("New book").author("Ivan").build();
    Book book2 = Book.builder().name("This book").author("Whatever").build();

    List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(book1, book2));

    Mockito.when(bookController.getAllBooks()).thenReturn(bookList);

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/books/all")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", is("New book")));
}

@Test
public void findByTitle_success() throws Exception {
    Book book = Book.builder().name("New book").author("Ivan")
            .pagesNumber(340).publisher("New Publisher").build();

    BookDto dto = converter.toDto(book);

    Mockito.when(bookController.findByTitle(book.getName())).thenReturn(dto);

    LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    requestParams.add("name", "New book");

    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/books/byTitle").params(requestParams)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
private String asJsonString(final Object obj){
    try{
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

P.S. Is there any article or documentation about implementing authentication in tests? Will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `@WebMvcTest(YourController.class` instead of `@SpringBootTest`, this will prevent Spring Boot to load the entire application to test just one layer

Answer (score 0):

Check the Spring Security Documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.6.5/servlet/test/method.html#test-method-withmockuser

You can use the `@WithMockUser` annotation, which provides default credentials with username - user and password - password, and with the role - ROLE_USER